How do I fix a schema error in a metaschema table _Field? Column _Format in table PUB._Field has value exceeding its max length or precision."
I'm working with a Progress 9.1E database application. (Yes, I'm aware of how bad that sounds).
My problem began when I ran SELECT * FROM SYSPROGRESS.SYSCOLUMNS_FULL, ...which gave me this error:

ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC PROGRESS driver][PROGRESS]Column _Format in table PUB._Field has value exceeding its max length or precision.

(For those unaware, the SYSCOLUMNS_FULL table is actually a SQL VIEW that's defined in PUB._Sysviews, and it's defined as (essentially) SELECT ... FROM PUB._Field INNER JOIN PUB._File)
Now if this was a normal user table then the solution is to edit the SQL Width of that column in the Data Dictionary tool - but the problem here is that _Field is a built-in metaschema table, and the Data Dictionary tool does not allow editing of the SQL Width of its columns.
...but I figured out that you can Unfreeze the table, then edit it, then re-Freeze it, which is what I did: I changed _Format's SQL Width to 1024 chars:

...and disregarded the dire warning...

...and I fully restarted the machine (as the _mprosrv.exe and _sqlsrv2.exe processes keep the schema cached indefinitely, I understand).
...and it did not fix the problem.

So my next was to run DBTool's "SQL Width & Date Scan w/Report Option" and "SQL Width Scan w/Fix Option" modes; which reported finding zero SQL Width errors (and only a single Date error).

So my next step was to try to see what's in PUB._Field that could cause this; so I ran this query:
SELECT
    t."_File-Name"  AS Tbl,
    f."_Field-Name" AS Col,
    f."_Data-Type"  AS Typ,
    f."_Format"     AS Fmt,
    f."_Width"      AS Wid

FROM
    PUB."_Field" AS f
    INNER JOIN PUB."_File" AS t ON f."_File-recid" = t.ROWID

...which gave me the same error as above. Which makes sense: clearly I can't access or use the "_Format" directly without causing that error, so I tried the trick where you use the ODBC scalar-function escape syntax, which should prevent "bad values" from being exposed to the ODBC layer:
SELECT
    { fn LENGTH( ""_Format"" ) } AS len
FROM
    PUB.""_Field""

...and this did not fix the problem.

So I used the Data Administration tool to dump the _Field metaschema table/view to a .d file - as well as Exporting it to CSV so I could open it in Excel.
Here's the Text dump opened in Excel, with all rows sorted (descending) by the length of their _Format column value:

...and the longest defined _Format value is 65 characters long.
...so perhaps the problem isn't _Format at all, but is some bug somewhere else that merely presents itself this way? Either way, this is beyond my current abilities.

So, I'm stumped - and because this version is so out-of-date there's no option for professional support.

It looks like the problem is the that actual value of the _format field is disagreeable to your client. Those fields are formatted for the maximum possible decimal value - 50 digits plus commas etc. Even if the fields were to get used (and they look like extra "just in case" fields to me) it seems pretty unlikely that they will have values that large. So do something like:
for each _field:

  if _field-name begins "_" and _format begins "->,>>" and length( _format ) > 40 then
    _format = "->,>>>,>>>,>>9.9999999999" no-error.

end.

(Obviously do this in a test system first.)

When I ran this in the Procedure Editor it complained the names weren't recognized, so I changed the names to _Field  and _Format, and that passed the Syntax Check OK, but then gives me this error: "Table _Sysnumstat  and its indexes can be modified or dropped only by SQL92. (6547)" - I don't know where it's getting _Sysnumstat from...

UPDATE: ...after clicking through about a dozen other popups with the same warning eventually it finished; then I restarted everything but alas, I'm still getting the "Column _Format in table PUB._Field has value exceeding its max length or precision." error.

BTW, because Progress included a lot of their debug symbols (*.map and .pdb) on their installation media (and even sourcedumps from their POSSENET and NuSphere days) I've been able to solve a bunch of other issues I've had with Progress with the help of Ghidra and WinDbg - but unfortunately in this case, the _sqlsrv2.exe symbols weren't included on the 9.1E installation media - I don't suppose you know if it's possible to get them at all?

I modified the code slightly, adding NO-ERROR should skip over the _sysnumstat table problem.  Although that might defeat the whole purpose. Then again it might get you to where you can change that table from the SQL side.

Sorry, no idea where to get _sqlsrv2.exe symbols.

Slight update: through trial-and-error (i.e. iterating over every _File) I've found the error is caused by -File-Number -108 and 32799 - and those weren't included in DA's dump of _Field for some reason.

I've narrowed it down to the _Format and _Width on the _Sysnumstat table - unfortunately I'm stuck again because _Sysnumstat is frozen, but I can't unfreeze it using DataAdmin/4GL/ABL because _"Table Sysnumstat  and its indexes can be modified or dropped only by SQL92. (6547)" - and I can't set PRO_SQL_WIDTH because 9.1E doesn't support ALTER TABLE. (This is maddening). Do you have any suggestions?

Can you use the sql92 engine to update the appropriate _field record? I'm not a SQL guy but something like "select * from _field where _field._file-recid = 4382 and _field-name = "_value" followed by an update of _format?

Unfortunately no; any attempt to do UPDATE PUB._Field SET... gives me the "Attempt to insert, update or delete a row in a schema table. (8186)" error.

sysnumstat is used by the query optimizer:

Contains one row for each column of data type NUMERIC. Used by the optimizer, each row contains a sampling of values in the column.

So you may be able to undo update statistics, after which, if you are using SQL you probably want to update statistics again, running into the same problem again.
